# Abrir 2 janelas e fechar uma de cada vez

Tags: jquery, fancybox

No fancybox eu abro duas janelas do plugin e preciso fechar uma de cada vez...

Exemplo: quando abrir a primeira janela só fecha a primeira e quando abrir a segunda só fecha a segunda, a primeira continua aberta quando fecha a segunda...

fiz um exemplo no jsfiddle com as duas janelas e ele fecha as duas quando fecho a segunda...
http://jsfiddle.net/g3R75/1/

Comment: A princípio, o fancybox reutiliza o mesmo DOM para os dois overlays (o que gera o problema), há uma pergunta do SO EN que sugere um workaround para resolver o problema. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973380/using-fancybox-version-2-when-closing-2nd-fancybox-reopen-first-fancybox-inste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em 30 de Julho de 2013, o utilizador @JFK abriu um *Bug Report* para o cenário com que estás a lidar:

[Multiple inline content and lock issue when opening fancybox from within fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/672)

Essencialmente, se tu tens vários conteúdos *inline* e tentas abrir uma FancyBox a partir do conteúdo de uma já aberta, recebes um erro:

```
TypeError: this.overlay is null
```

E a operação é interrompida.

Até  ao momento não existe resolução para este problema reportado pela FancyBox.

---

## Solução

Como solução podemos trabalhar apenas com uma instância da FancyBox, a que o utilizador vai abrir em primeiro lugar, alterando o conteúdo da mesma mediante a navegação do utilizador:

[**Ver demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/3vwZr/)

**HTML**

```html
<a id="fancy1" href="#modal1">Abrir FancyBox 01</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="modal1">
        <a id="fancy2" href="#">Abrir FancyBox 02</a>
    </div>
    <div id="modal2">
        Teste2
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
// Instanciar a primeira popup
$("#fancy1").fancybox({
    closeBtn: false,
    hideOnContentClick: true,
    padding: 0,
    fitToView: false,
    autoCenter: true,
    type: 'inline',
    helpers: {
      overlay: {
        css: {
          'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)'
        }
      }
    }
});

/* Anexar um evento de clique no que seria a chamada da segunda popup
 * para que possamos trocar o HTML da primeira pelo HTML da segunda
 */
$('body').on("click", '#fancy2', function(){
    $.fancybox.open({
        closeBtn: false,
        href: "#modal2",
        type: 'inline',
        afterClose: function() {
            /* Chamar a primeira popup quando o
             * utilizador quer sair da segunda
             */
            $("#fancy1").trigger("click");
        }
    });
});
```

## Explicação

- Utilizador clica para abrir a primeira *popup*, a FancyBox executa normalmente;
- utilizador clica para abrir a segunda *popup*, o que fazemos é substituir o conteúdo da primeira *popup* pelo conteúdo da segunda;
- O utilizador fecha a segunda *popup*, disparamos um *click* na chamada da FancyBox, trazendo assim de volta o conteúdo original.
- O utilizador fecha a primeira *popup*, a FancyBox fecha normalmente.

Essencialmente estamos sempre a lidar com a chamada da FancyBox, mas duma forma em que não temos o evento da mesma anexado à chamada da segunda *modal inline*. Desta forma contornamos o problema existente na FancyBox e resolvemos o teu.

---

**Nota:**

O que o utilizador @Wakim mencionou no comentário está correcto, a FancyBox faz uso de uma única estrutura de DOM para alternar entre conteúdos e/ou chamadas diferentes, motivo o qual o Bug que salientei existe.

Quando dizes na tua pergunta que ele fecha as duas, o que acontece é que ele fecha a única que existe instanciada. Na realidade nunca existe mais que uma instância da FancyBox.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri uma outra forma de fazer isso tambem no stackoverflow gringo...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463658/close-2-modal-and-open-1-again/24465132#24465132

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RR9Z4/**

Usando o callback afterClose,

```
afterClose: function () {
    if (this.element.attr("id") == "fancybox-button3") {
        $("#button2").click();
    }
}
```